# Issue while splitting pandas dataframe column into n columns

Tags: python, string, pandas, split

I have a dataframe with below column `Title`. Each sentence is repeating three times. I want to split into three columns evenly.

```
    Title
0  [1.3] Avg ticket size - merchant vs industry and benchamark (processed data).[1.3] Avg ticket size - merchant vs industry and benchamark (processed data).[1.3] Avg ticket size - merchant vs industry and benchamark (processed data)
1  [10.1] Overall portfolio and benchmarks for the bank over the last 5 quarters.[10.1] Overall portfolio and benchmarks for the bank over the last 5 quarters.[10.1] Overall portfolio and benchmarks for the bank over the last 5 quarters
2  [10.10] Decline Reasons (Quarter-wise)- E-Com vs. POS and comparison with benchmark.[10.10] Decline Reasons (Quarter-wise)- E-Com vs. POS and comparison with benchmark.[10.10] Decline Reasons (Quarter-wise)- E-Com vs. POS and comparison with benchmark
3  [10.2] QoQ Pct of Transaction Method Spend, Transaction Method Active Cards.[10.2] QoQ Pct of Transaction Method Spend, Transaction Method Active Cards.[10.2] QoQ Pct of Transaction Method Spend, Transaction Method Active Cards
4  [10.3] Pct of Transaction Method Spend, Transaction Method Active Cards by Product Type.[10.3] Pct of Transaction Method Spend, Transaction Method Active Cards by Product Type.[10.3] Pct of Transaction Method Spend, Transaction Method Active Cards by Product Type
5  [10.4] QoQ of average ticket size, transactions per card, average spend per card.[10.4] QoQ of average ticket size, transactions per card, average spend per card.[10.4] QoQ of average ticket size, transactions per card, average spend per card
```

I tried below code but did not work as expected.

```
import textwrap
pd.DataFrame([textwrap.wrap(el, len(el)//3) for el in df['Title']]).add_prefix('Title')
```

**I want to split by finding the length of string and then split based on len(string)/3. Because sometimes there will be . in middle of sentence**

Please help

Comment: Use anky's solution in your other post, but use `np.array_split` instead of `np.split`

Comment: split by `len(string)/3` will never break your strings into 3 complete sentences. The reason is each string got repeated 3 times but you added spaces and the period mark `'.'` to them. Therefore, `len(repeated-sentence)` is not equal to sum of len of 3 completed sentences.

Comment: I got the issue. I just modified 'yatu` solution by adding 1 to `len` variable. The solution works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you can use [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) here:

```
df.Title.str.split(r'\[\d+\.\d+\]\s', expand=True)

0                                                  1  \
0    Avg ticket size - merchant vs industry and ben...   
1    Overall portfolio and benchmarks for the bank ...   
2    Decline Reasons (Quarter-wise)- E-Com vs. POS ...   
3    QoQ Pct of Transaction Method Spend, Transacti...   
4    Pct of Transaction Method Spend, Transaction M...   
5    QoQ of average ticket size, transactions per c...   

                                                   2  \
0  Avg ticket size - merchant vs industry and ben...   
1  Overall portfolio and benchmarks for the bank ...   
2  Decline Reasons (Quarter-wise)- E-Com vs. POS ...   
3  QoQ Pct of Transaction Method Spend, Transacti...   
4  Pct of Transaction Method Spend, Transaction M...   
5  QoQ of average ticket size, transactions per c...   

                                                   3  
0  Avg ticket size - merchant vs industry and ben...  
1  Overall portfolio and benchmarks for the bank ...  
2  Decline Reasons (Quarter-wise)- E-Com vs. POS ...  
3  QoQ Pct of Transaction Method Spend, Transacti...  
4  Pct of Transaction Method Spend, Transaction M...  
5  QoQ of average ticket size, transactions per c...
```

---

**Update**

If you want to find the length of the strings in each row and split into 3, one approach could be:

```
n = 3
lens = df.Title.str.len()//n
l = [[i[(c-1)*sl:c*sl] for i, sl in zip(df.Title, lens)] for c in range(1, n+1)]
pd.DataFrame.from_records(l).T

                                0  \
0  [1.3] Avg ticket size - merchant vs industry a...   
1  [10.1] Overall portfolio and benchmarks for th...   
2  [10.10] Decline Reasons (Quarter-wise)- E-Com ...   
3  [10.2] QoQ Pct of Transaction Method Spend, Tr...   
4  [10.3] Pct of Transaction Method Spend, Transa...   
5  [10.4] QoQ of average ticket size, transaction...   

                                                   1  \
0  .[1.3] Avg ticket size - merchant vs industry ...   
1  .[10.1] Overall portfolio and benchmarks for t...   
2  .[10.10] Decline Reasons (Quarter-wise)- E-Com...   
3  .[10.2] QoQ Pct of Transaction Method Spend, T...   
4  .[10.3] Pct of Transaction Method Spend, Trans...   
5  .[10.4] QoQ of average ticket size, transactio...   

                                                   2  
0  ).[1.3] Avg ticket size - merchant vs industry...  
1  s.[10.1] Overall portfolio and benchmarks for ...  
2  k.[10.10] Decline Reasons (Quarter-wise)- E-Co...  
3  s.[10.2] QoQ Pct of Transaction Method Spend, ...  
4  e.[10.3] Pct of Transaction Method Spend, Tran...  
5  d.[10.4] QoQ of average ticket size, transacti...
```

Comment: @yatu.Is it is possible to find the length of string and then split based on `len(string)/3`. Because sometimes there will be `.` in middle of sentence.

Comment: Updated @Arvinth

Answer (score 1):

Instead of divide the length by 3, you can use regex to split the string.

Note that such a split pattern can be defined as:

```
r'\.(?=\[)'
```

i.e.:

- `\.` - a (literal) dot,
- `(?=\[\d+\.\d+])` - followed by *[*, a sequence of digits, another dot,
  another sequence of digits and *]*.

Note that the second part is a *positive lookahead*, so it will not be
a part of match and this *[nn,mm]* fragment will be the starting part
of the next string (result of split).

You didn't write about deleting this *[nn,mm]* fragment, so it should
remain in the result of the split and this is the downside of the other
answer.

So the code generating *df* concatenated with 3 new columns can be:

```
df2 = pd.concat([df, df.Title.str.split(
    r'\.(?=\[\d+\.\d+])', expand=True)], axis=1)
```